# shared_preferences returns null on existing value

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I am trying to see if an id key is available in my app's shared_pereferences and if there is, redirect my user to the homepage. I am checking the Id in the initState() function of my main.dart and I know that the id exists because I can get it in other pages. but in my main.dart it returns null. any ideas?
here is my main.dart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import './ui/pages/auth/auth_one.dart';
import './ui/pages/main_page.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
          [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((_) => runApp(MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String userId;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _getUserId().then((id) => userId = id);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(userId);
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: userId == null ? AuthOne() : MainPage(),
    );
  }

  _getUserId() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var id = prefs.getString('id');
    return id;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `_getUserId` method is async, so you will have to refresh the widget after you get the result.

Use this:

```
         @override
          void initState() {
            _getUserId().then((id) { 
              //calling setState will refresh your build method.
              setState(() {
                userId = id;
              });
            });
            super.initState();
          }
```

Comment: `super.initState()` should always be the first line in the method.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are trying to use the value before its calculated.

> you could use timer function for delay